# Pyspark. Out of memory problems. How to make sure that tables are overwritten

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, machine-learning, pyspark

I currently try to understand the the processes of Spark calculations and the effects on the memory consumption.

I’m working with Spark 2.3.2 and Python 2.7 in Zeppelin.

Basically in the following loop I’m creating to sets. I’m building a machine learning model with sci-kit-learn and I’m doing a lot of dataframe operations on pyspark-dataframes after the sci-kit-learn calculations. And for each i I get a table rsmeMaeStep with 8 rows and 10 columns with small string or double values. The rsmeMaeAll is just adding the single analysis together and has 8*26 =208 rows with 10 columns for i=26.

```
for i in range(26):
    df_features_train, df_features_validation = randomizer(dataFiltered)
    rsmeMaeStep, rsmeMaeAll = rsmeMaeAnalysis(rsmeMaeAll,df_features_train,df_features_test)
    print(i)
```

I made some time analysis for the code. For i=1 it took 17 seconds for i=10: 2:40 mnutes for i =26 it tooks 6:42. (i.e. 9.4 or 23.6 times longer for 10 or 26 loops.) So far, everything as expected.
I have a problem in the next step. The following code should just to a simple aggregation on 8 to 206 rows. For i=1 it tooks 32 seconds, for i=7 4:43 (8.8 times longer) but for i=26 I have 0% after 47 minutes or it fails with a out of memory message.

```
rsmeMae = rsmeMaeAll.select('set','setting','sme').orderBy('set','setting')
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
rsmeMaeAverage = rsmeMae.groupBy('setting','set').agg(f.count(('setting')).alias('nrOfRand'), f.round(f.mean('sme'),2).alias('rsme'),f.round(f.stddev('sme'),2).alias('sigmaRsme')).orderBy('set','setting')
z.show(rsmeMaeAverage)
```

Based on the logic I thought of all the tables should be overwritten in each loop. Only the small rsmeMaeAll should increase a bit, with each loop. But it’s still a very small table.

But Spark is probably acting differently.

As I understand the situation the sk-learn code of the first step is executed in the first step. If I do understand the spark lazy evaluation correctly the pySpark operations in my code starts to be executed when I want to print the results. Therefore, Spark is maybe saving all the tables of all the loops in memory. Is that right?

If I’m right I would need the code to calculate the pySpark code directly at the end of each loop.

How may I do this?

And if I do this will spark overwrite the tables in the next loop or will the memory consumption still rise with each loop? Would I need to delete the tables actively out of the memory and how?

**edit:** I just integrated

```
rsmeMaeStep.collect()
rsmeMaeAll.collect()
```

into the loop to make sure that the pyspark calculation are done right away. 
But while the first loop took 55 seconds. The 7th took more than 10 minutes and it cruched at the rsmeMaeAll.collect() of the 8th loop after 49 minutes. With the error message:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o13488.collectToPython. :java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I really don't understand the exponential rise of time per loop. And before I was at least able to run 10 loops. What is happening there?

Comment: rsmeMaeAll is not that big of a table for the OOM error when going from pandas df to spark df. How big is your cluster? Can you allocate more resources?

Comment: My cluster has 12 CPU's and 64 GByte memory. And today I am the only one working on it. The dataFrames I produce in every loop are quite large. My problem would be solved if I could just finish all calculations of a loop until the end of the loop. And if all tables created during the loop, except the output in the next loop, were deleted or overwritten.

Comment: Now I'm confused, where is rsmeMaeAnalysis executed? On the spark side or sci-kit learn side?

Comment: It is first doing a lot of ridge regressions with scikit learn. Then a couple of dataFrame opererations on 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame' - tables. 

I produce a lot of big dataframes **inside** the loops. rsmeMaeAll is just the summary of the results. 

And I need the dataframes **inside** the loops should as well as df_features_train, df_features_validation of one loop deleted before or overwritten by the next loop.

At least I think that this would solve the problem.

Comment: I found a solution and will post it in the next days in more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem had something to do with the lazy evaluation in Spark. And since I gathered all informations the pyspark dataframe rsmeMaeAll maybe all the information necessary to produce rsmeMaeAll have been loaded in the cache at the same time while I tried to calculate an output.

Based on this idea I rebuild the code in a way that Spark does not have to keep all the steps in between anymore. Additionally, I integrated a time measurement and I rebuild the old code in two variants to make one variant closer to the new logic and every variant in a way that the calculation has to be done at the end of every loop.

The solution was the following:

```
for i in range(9):
    ti0 = time.time()
    df_features_train, df_features_test = randomizer(dataFiltered)
    rsmeMaeStep = rsmeMaeAnalysis(df_features_train,df_features_test)
    rsmeMaeAllpd = rsmeMaeAllpd.append(rsmeMaeStep.toPandas())
    print(rsmeMaeAllpd)
    ti1 = time.time()
    print "Time for loop", i, ":", ti1-ti0
```

In rsmeMaeAnalysis I have just calculated the results of an analysis, returned them, converted them into a Pandas dataframe and collected all the results in Pandas. The result was that each loop took more or less the same time and even after 20 loops I had no memory problems. The time for the first ten loops have been the following:

> 41s ,42s ,44s ,40s ,43s ,43s ,40s ,39s ,40s ,40s

But then I wanted to be sure that the gathering of the results in a pyspark dataframe really have been the problem therefore I build a code as close as possible to the pandas-solution but with a gathering of the results in a pyspark dataframe:

```
for i in range(10):
    ti0 = time.time()
    df_features_train, df_features_test = randomizer(dataFiltered)
    rsmeMaeStep = rsmeMaeAnalysis(df_features_train,df_features_test)
    rsmeMaeAll = rsmeMaeAll.union(rsmeMaeStep)
    rsmeMaeAll.show(80,False)
    ti1 = time.time()
    print "Time for loop", i, ":", ti1-ti0
```

The time for the first eight loops was the following:

> 43s ,63s ,88s ,144s ,162s ,175s ,212s ,276s

In the original variant just with time measurement it took the following times until an out of memory error after the 7th loop:

> 44s ,60s ,73s ,98s ,128s ,157s ,198s

At the end it stil seems like the lazy evaluation causes that  alot of the information necessary to produce rsmeMaeAll have been loaded in the cache at the same time although most of the information are not relevant at the end of each loop.

Comment: Although I have now solved the problem for myself, I would still find it exciting to understand why exactly the time takes longer and the memory problems occur.

Comment: There is a spark-sklearn package that you can use to try to run the models in parallel to get any further speedup https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn